# send Google Charts options via callback

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

How can I send chart options from my callback function?

I have the following javascript function but would like to get the chart options from my callback. The problem is that I don't know how to "echo the json table" as well as passing the options.

```
currentId = $('#currentId').attr('value');
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRevenue);

function drawRevenue() {
    // Define the chart to be drawn.
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Settings.base_url+"xxController/draw",
        data: "currentID="+currentId+"&table=cash",
        dataType:"json",
        async: false
        }).responseText;

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    // Set options the chart.
    // This is the part I want to get dynamically from the callback (I have more options)
    var options = {title:titleRevenueChart};
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart')); 
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

My callback funtion (simplyfied):

```
 public function draw_revenue(){            

        $graph_data = $this->xxxModel->get_history($currentID, $table, $graph_start_date);

        $rows = array();
        foreach($graph_data->result() as $row){
            $temp = array();
            $table_values['cols'] = array(
            //Labels for the chart, these represent the column titles
            array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
            array('id' => '', 'label' => $table, 'type' => 'number')
            );
            //Values
            $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row->date);
            $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $row->$table); 
            $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
        }

        $graph_data->free_result();
        $table_values['rows'] = $rows;

        $jsonTable = json_encode($table_values, true);
        echo $jsonTable;
// How can I add some options generated from the callback to my chart? Such as title, depending of the date...
    }
```

UPDATE:
It worked fine using @WhiteHat code but I had to change the way I retrieve the arrays in the JS function. The following worked:

```
var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData[0]['data']);
var options = jsonData[1]['options'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in php, you can use another `array()` to package the data and options together...

```
public function draw_revenue(){
    $graph_data = $this->xxxModel->get_history($currentID, $table, $graph_start_date);

    $rows = array();
    foreach($graph_data->result() as $row){
        $temp = array();
        $table_values['cols'] = array(
        //Labels for the chart, these represent the column titles
        array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('id' => '', 'label' => $table, 'type' => 'number')
        );
        //Values
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row->date);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $row->$table);
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

    $graph_data->free_result();
    $table_values['rows'] = $rows;

    $chart_options = array('title' => 'Chart Title');

    $chart_package = array();
    $chart_package[] = array('data' => $table_values);
    $chart_package[] = array('options' => $chart_options);

    $jsonTable = json_encode($chart_package, true);
    echo $jsonTable;
}
```

then split them back out in the javascript

**note:** highly recommend not using `async: false`

```
currentId = $('#currentId').attr('value');
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRevenue);

function drawRevenue() {
    // Define the chart to be drawn.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Settings.base_url+"xxController/draw",
        data: "currentID="+currentId+"&table=cash",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (jsonData) {
      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData.data);
      // Set options the chart.
      var options = jsonData.options;
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```

Comment: It almost works! when using your code I get an error message saying there is no column. I figured out that the `data` array is not sent to JS. If I switch the `data` and `options` line in the $chart_package definition, then the `options` are missing. Can you see what is wrong with both lines?

Comment: yes, sorry, looks like i forgot to add the brackets `[]` when adding to the new array, i changed the answer above...

Comment: Not yet, the two arrays are sent to the JS but I get `undefined` when I alert `(jsonData.data)` or `(jsonData.options)`. I will try to get that fixed tomorrow and update the topic!

Comment: np, just wanted to make sure you noticed the changes i made above to --> `$chart_package[]`

Comment: Got it to work using modifying slightly the way I retrieve the array in JS. I will update my post. Thanks!